# Fix 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH; geckodriver path is specified

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to use selenium to do some simple webscraping, and I need to use selenium to deal with the dynamic content.

I have tried downloading geckodriver several times, and have put geckodriver into the same directory and specified the path when creating the driver in the code.

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/usr/local/Cellar/geckodrivers/0.24.0/bin/geckodriver'
```

I expected this to work, but still got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Any idea what else I can try? Thank you!

Comment: Does your geckodriver has executable permission ?

Comment: Does it work if you specify absolute path?

Comment: For adding path: ```export PATH=$PATH:/path_to_geckodriver```

Comment: Just use the WebDriverManager and you should have no problem: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: place it somewhere on your system PATH (hint: it is an environment variable in your shell)